# What is the new class or alternative to AuthChallengeParser?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on migrating some legacy code from HTTPClient 3 and HTTPClient 4, and in the codebase, we've used a class known as `AuthChallengeParser`.

In particular, we use this [extractScheme](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/AuthChallengeParser.html#extractScheme(java.lang.String)). However, I can't seem to find a class that does the same thing in HTTPClient 4.

It also seems like the class is entirely removed (not even deprecated). I haven't been able to find any other Javadocs on `AuthChallengeParser` aside from the one in HTTPClient 3.

Currently, my solution is to utilize the source code of `AuthChallengeParser` just for `extractScheme()`. While I am aware that using deprecated or removed code is usually a bad idea, I believe there is no real issues with the code considering it just creates a substring, as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any idea on what is the alternative to `AuthChallengeParser`?

Answer (score 0):

It is [AuthSchemeBase#processChallenge](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/auth/AuthSchemeBase.java#L88) and [RFC2617Scheme#parseChallenge](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/auth/RFC2617Scheme.java#L111)